# Sharepoint online - Issues adding an app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I am new to Sharepoint and I am creating a simple company Intranet site using Sharepoint Online. I have been able to add apps to the web parts no problem until today.

I have added a new app from the Sharepoint store and when I try to add it to the page it is not showing in the list of apps. 
 
I have added some more apps to see if it would do this with them and they aren't showing up either.

Comment: You can able to add the app in a Site only one time. After that where ever you want, you can use its client web part.

Comment: Hi, sorry for getting back so late @NaveenPrasath. I am not trying to add the same app twice. I have downloaded some apps and they're are in my site contents. When I click 'edit page' and 'add a web part' the apps i have downloaded are not in that list. I am struggling to find any answers online for this issue :(

Comment: Does the app having the client webparts? If there is no client webpart in the page, it will not shown in apps group. Also check your app in Custom group too.